# MySql If record does not exist in Table B, add to Table B and Increment Col in Table A else only add to Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating something to record the number of views for each item. The views for each item are increment only if a user has not previously viewed it.

I'm using 2 tables,

```
`itemsMain` is the main table
id  |  itemTitle  | itemViews
--------------------------------
 1  |  Item 1     | 1
 2  |  Item 2     | 1
```

`itemStats` is the table that records each view. Even if the same user were to view the same item twice, a record is inserted. `(Helps for analysis later)`.

```
genId | itemId | itemViewedUserId |
  1   |   1    |   1
  2   |   1    |   1
```

Here, `userId 1` has viewed `itemId 1` once and so the itemViews in `itemsMain` is 1.

However, if he views the same `itemId 1` again, a record needs to be inserted into `itemStats` but the `itemViews` col in `itemsMain` need not be incremented.

How can something like this be done? I presently use php to select if a record exists and then do the increment.

Is something like this doable in just a single sql statement?

It all work out like this:
If a matching record is found in `itemStats` => Add the record to `itemStats`, but do not increment `itemViews` in `itemsMain`

If a matching record is not found in `itemStats` => Add the record to `itemStats`, but increment `itemViews` in `itemsMain`

A record needs to inserted into `itemsStats` regardless if it there or not, but the incrementing needs to be done only if a record in `itemsStats` did not exists.

Example:

```
insert into itemStats (1,2) //Adds the record to `itemStats` as well as increments `itemViews` in `itemsMain`

insert into itemStats (1,2) //Adds the record to `itemStats` but no increment to `itemViews` in `itemsMain`
```

Comment: I think you are infinitely better off just using Count(genId) from itemStats group by itemId for any times you need a count of how many people have viewed it

Comment: :-( No way to do it with sql? I currently do it the way you suggested. Was thinking of changing that.

Comment: I mean, you could set itemViews = (select Count(genID) from itemStats group by itemId where itemStats.itemId = itemsMain.id) or something, run that query when you run the insert statement, or have a stored procedure do it every so often